# KeyLisenter, repaint(), methods

Tags: java, applet

Ok, I have been workinng of mending this for the past hour or more. I wanted to seperate the player class and the applet being drawn for convience when I add more to the player class it will be more organized. But, since I did this I have had error after error and I have another file similiar to this one where it draws the applet in the same file with no errors and runs. I have looked at it step by step and still can not find it. So I was hoping somebody could explain why I am getting these three errors.

player.java

```
package com.powder.game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class player implements KeyListener{

private Rectangle rect;
public void init(){
    rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50); // make the rectangle

    this.addKeyListener(this); // Listens to see if Rectangle is pressed
}

    public void paint(Graphics e){
    super.paint(e);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) e;

    g2.setColor(Color.RED); // Sets a color for the rectangle
    g2.fill(rect);
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_E){
        rect.setLocation(rect.x, rect.y-10);
    }

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
        rect.setLocation(rect.x-10, rect.y);
    }

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
        rect.setLocation(rect.x, rect.y+10);
    }

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F){
        rect.setLocation(rect.x+10, rect.y);
    }
    repaint();
}

public void KeyReleased(KeyEvent e){

}
}
```

MyFrameInit.java

```
package com.powder.game;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Math;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import com.powder.game.player;

public class MyFrameInit extends Applet {

player p = new player();

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g); // Super calls the parent
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE); // Setting color for g (background)
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 400); // fill the background blue at x,y,width,height
    this.setSize(600, 400);  // Set the size of the applet
    p.init();
}
}
```

Sorry if the formatting for the page isn't right. Still trying to understand this. I'm so used to tags lol.

EDIT: So, I extended Applet to player and it fixed almost everything I just added

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

that to the end and it started to work. Now my only problem is it's not keeping MyFrameInit.java when after I go to init() in player.java how could I fix this?

Comment: *"I have had error after error"* - Like what?

Comment: Harsh advice, but you may be better off throwing out this code starting over since you've got lots of problems going on and seem to be coding by guessing. When coding, if you can't use an IDE that immediately flags for any compilation errors, then you must compile your code early and often, and not add any new code until all compilation errors have been fixed.

Comment: Things to keep in mind: 1) If you must use an applet, then don't forget to override its `init()` method. 2( Better to use Swing JApplets rather than AWT Applets. 3) You can only add a KeyListener to a class that in fact has an `addKeyListener(...)` method such as classes that extend Swing or AWT components. Check what you're doing instead. 4) If your class implements an interface, it must implement **all** of the methods of that interface (e.g., KeyListener)...

Comment: Regarding, `"So, I extended Applet to player and it fixed almost everything I just added..."` -- this is very very wrong. You shouldn't be adding an applet to an applet. Rather Player should extend JPanel or somesuch, and you really need to read the tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

## Problems

`Player` does not have methods...

- `addKeyListener`
- `repaint`

It does not inherit from anything, therefore it can't call...

- `super.paint`, as it's parent classes do not have this method...

You can't call what you don't have...

`Player` does not meet to contractual requirements of the `KeyListener` interface, it does not implement

- `public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)`

Painting is for painting the current state of the component, you should never modify the state of the component or any child components from within any paint method, as this can produce an infinite loop of repaints

Don't do:

- `this.setSize(600, 400);  // Set the size of the applet` - You should never try and set the size of an applet, the size is determined by the HTML tag
- `p.init();`.  Your `paint` method will be called a lot of times over the life cycle of your program, it's pointless to initialise objects within that require there state to be maintained between calls

## Recommendations

- Start by using a `JApplet` instead of an `Applet`
- Extending your `Player` from a `JPanel`; override it's `paintComponent` method instead of it's `paint` method (calling `super.paintComponent` instead); override it's `getPreferredSize` method and return a reasonable default size for the component
- `add` `Player` to the `JApplet`...
- Use the key bindings API instead of `KeyListener`, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).  This will save you a few more days of head scratching and frustration.